# windbg script causes memory access violation

Tags: windbg

I am using the following windbg script to break when a certain value is encountered in the buffer when reading a file

```
bp ReadFile

.while(1)
{
  g

  $$ Get parameters of ReadFile()
  r $t0 = dwo(esp+4)
  r $t1 = dwo(esp+8)
  r $t2 = dwo(esp+0x0c)

  $$ Execute until return is reached
  pt

  $$ Read magic value in the buffer
  $$ CHANGE position in buffer here
  r $t5 = dwo(@$t1+0x00)

  $$ Check if magic value matches
  $$ CHANGE constant here
  .if(@$t5 == 0x70170000)
  {
    $$db @$t1

    $$ break
    .break
  }
}

$$ Clear BP for ReadFile (assume it is the 0th one)
bc 0
```

I get the following memory access violation when I run this script.

```
Memory access error at ');;  $$ Check if magic value matches;  $$ CHANGE constant here;  .if(@$t5 == 0x70170000);  {;    $$db @$t1;;    $$ break;    .break;  };'
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: The `@$t5` dereferences the memory the `$t5` variable is pointing to, and in your case, the memory adress is wrong / not accessible. Check the logic of what adress should be assigned to this variable. What exactly are you trying to do with this script?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I am trying to break when the output buffer during a file read starts with 0x70170000. $t1 contains the memory address of the output buffer. $t5 should contain the contents of the memory at address $t1.

Comment: Assuming esp is valid, the only thing that stands out is @$t1 is not a valid address and it's the `dwo(@$t1+0x00)` that's reporting the access error.

Comment: When it breaks, can you do a `dd @$t1`? Does it show question marks then?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes it does. How is this possible? `$t1` is supposed to have the pointer to the output buffer. instead it contains a null pointer `00000000`

Comment: Is it possible that the script breaks for some other reason than the breakpoint after `g`? In that case your script is not in `ReadFile()` as expected by the script. What does `k` say?

Comment: k says `002c6b78 76fe9d12 KERNELBASE!ReadFile` at the top, so the script should be in `ReadFile()`. I have also verified this by looking at the disassembly.

Comment: BTW: your script may not work in all cases. If someone e.g. reads the file byte by byte, the buffer will never contain the magic value (4 bytes). The same applies if you read 1 byte first, then the rest. In that case, the offset will differ by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to read the buffer contents at kernel32!ReadFile you need to save the buffer address and step out of the function using gu (goup or step out)

when broken on ReadFile esp+8 points to the buffer so save it and step out

r $t1 = poi(@esp+8);gu

the first Dword of the buffer is poi(@$t1) compare it with the required Dword
and take necessary action with .if .else

.if( poi(@$t1) != 636c6163 ) {gc} .else {db @$t1 l10;gc}

putting this all together in one line the script shoule be

```
bp k*32!ReadFile "r $t1 =poi(@esp+8);gu;.if((poi(@$t1))!=636c6163){gc}.else{db @$t1 l10;gc}"
```

here 636c6163 is 'clac' (calc reversed ) use the dword you want instead of this

a sample run on calc.exe xp sp3 32 bits

```
bl
bp k*32!ReadFile "r $t1=poi(@esp+8);gu;.if((poi(@$t1))!=636c6163){gc}.else{db @$t1 l10;gc}"
.bpcmds
bp0 0x7c801812  "r $t1 = poi(@esp+8);gu;.if( (poi(@$t1))!=636c6163){gc}.else{db @$t1 l10;gc}"
0:002> g
00b865b0  63 61 6c 63 5f 77 68 61-74 69 73 5f 69 6e 74 72  calc_whatis_intr
00374df0  63 61 6c 63 00 ab ab ab-ab ab ab ab ab fe ee fe  calc............
```